# First radio_button not showing in Rails 5

Tags: enums, devise, radio-button, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `Devise` within `Rails 5` and have added `Enum/roles` (Consumer, Designer) to the `User model`. When creating a new registration, I want the user to select a `role`, for which I've added a `radio_button` for each `value/role`:

```
<div id="user_role"
    <% User.roles.keys.each do |role| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :role, role %>
      <%= f.label role.to_sym %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

It's showing the `labels` of both roles, but only the `radio_button` for the last role. Here are the roles defined in the `User model`:

```
enum role: [:consumer, :designer]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this way

```
 <div id="user_role">
    <% User.roles.keys.each do |role| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :role, role %>
      <%= f.label role.to_sym %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
              or

  <div id="user_role">
   <% User.roles.each do |role| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :role, role %>
    <%= f.label role[0] %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

it's working fine in my local.I hope it's will be help you.

Comment: By trying out your example and testing it with inspector I discovered that I'm just stupid: I forgot the closing arrow for the first div... Thanks!!

Comment: Since you've delivered an excellent alternative, I think it's only fair to accept your answer ;)

Comment: thanks ..@Sebastian Plasschaert.. ohh..i also post answer then after see closing tag..